# Check the code below to help me centre my gmail button

Tags: html, button, html-email

I'm very very new to html. I'm mostly copy-pasting bits of code as my framework and customizing it to make my emails work. I have this bit of code for my email, but I can't seem to get the opt-in button to center. I've tried reading other similar questions, but my knowledge of coding is that of a beginner, and I can't understand how their coding solutions, in which the code is slightly different, relates to my code to find a solution. I was adding style=text-align: center; in a few spots, but it wasn't working. There were other solutions, but I didn't quite understand how they would work in my code. I've been trying to fix this things for hours now. So very frustrated.

Other than the centering it works in the email.

```
<td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; padding: 0px 10px 10px 
0px;">You've previously contacted us at Business Name.&nbsp;<br>We 
are <b>only sending this email once</b> to our current client list to 
invite you to join our new free monthly e-newsletter.&nbsp;<br>

 style="text-align: center;
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr>
  <td>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody><tr>
              <td style="border-radius: 2px;" bgcolor="#018736">
                  <a href="https://www.businessname.com/community- 
 newsletter.html" target="_blank" style="padding: 10px 32px; border: 1px 
 solid #018736;border-radius: 2px;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans- 
serif;font-size: 24px; color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;font- 
 weight:bold;display: inline-block;">
                      OPT-IN             
                  </a>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody></table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>


<br>Grief is a difficult thing. If you choose not to join our free 
monthly newsletter at this time we understand, but will not be sending 
any other emails to you going forward. <br><br></td>
```

Comment: Andreas, maybe you could offer solutions? I'm ask for help here.

Comment: Andreas, I'm a beginner. I have spent ALL DAY trying to figure this out, okay? I have been googling it and searching through forums that seem so confident and above my head, but I'm TRYING to learn. So, please don't judge and condemn me for asking for help.

Comment: I'm merely suggesting you to do basic tutorials since you are saying that you're a beginner, so that you could get a better understanding of your problem and the solutions that you could try. Also, you did not include in the question of what have you researched or tried so far. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code below:

```
 <td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; padding: 0px 10px 10px 
    0px;">You've previously contacted us at Handsome Stitchery.&nbsp;<br>We 
    are <b>only sending this email once</b> to our current client list to 
    invite you to join our new free monthly e-newsletter.&nbsp;<br>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
              <tbody><tr>
                  <td style="border-radius: 2px;" bgcolor="#018736">
                      <a href="https://www.handsomestitchery.com/community- 
     newsletter.html" target="_blank" style="padding: 10px 32px; border: 1px 
     solid #018736;border-radius: 2px;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans- 
    serif;font-size: 24px; color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;font- 
     weight:bold;display: inline-block;">
                          OPT-IN             
                      </a>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody></table>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody></table>


    <br>Grief is a difficult thing. If you choose not to join our free 
    monthly newsletter at this time we understand, but will not be sending 
    any other emails to you going forward. <br><br></td>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I'm trying to figure out exactly what you changed to make it so. Is it just the style="text-align:center;" after the first <td ? or am I missing something else. I had tried that, but must have been putting it in the wrong spot.

Comment: ok dear, its good that your problem is solved :) Profile pic nyc

Comment: sorry, mis-click on my end. Fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Going off what you have, I think throwing `style="text-align: center;` on the `<td>` that your link button is in should do the trick. Also you might want to get rid of the other style="text-align: center; that is floating above the first  tag, it is code that is showing up as text on your page.

Comment: cpru, thanks! I missed that floater. Got rid of it! Now, I'm not sure where to put the style="text-align: center; formatting. Do you mean after "target=" before the padding 10x x 32 x dimensions?

Comment: It would go in the td cell right above the opt in button. So it would be like `<td style="border-radius: 2px; text-align: center" bgcolor="#018736"`

Comment: thank you so much, that makes perfect sense now that you've explained it. Why doesn't the same code in the first line that centers the text above also affect the button?

Comment: CSS can be very odd sometimes. However, usually this type of styling affects what is known as "children" or its elements enclosed within it. The one you are referring to might be able to influence it, but it doesn't look like the button markup we are working with was within it, it could be that it was missing a closing tag. Whatever is going on, we were able to target it by adding the styling to one of its direct parent elements.